# Multi sites hosts on a virtualbox webserver

Tags: server, virtualbox, apache2, hosts

I have a LAMP server on Kubuntu running in virtualBox (NAT network).
I have two sites site1.conf and site2.conf too create virtualhosts
I have modify hosts to have access localy site1.local and site2.local
That work fine and i can access with my kubuntu webbroswer to my two sites.

If I try to access my site in my guest webbroswer (127.0.0.1:8080) with port forwarding (because nat configuration in virtualbox) i can only access site1
Now i want access site2 in my guest webbrowser.
I try modify hosts in guest but that do not work

How can i do ?

Answer (score 1):

The only information the client sends to the server via http(s) protocol is the "host" and the "path". From this the server has to find out what to send back.

How should a server know from the information "127.0.0.1" which of your sites (site1.conf or site2.conf) you want to access?

You need two different "names".

Add "127.0.0.1" as "ServerAlias" to "site1.conf" and "127.0.1.1" as ServerAlias to "site2.conf".

Now you can access site1 with "127.0.0.1:8080" and site2 with "127.0.1.1:8080".

All IPv4 addresses in subnet 127.0.0.0/8 are "localhost".

Comment: Hello, 
I try, but seems not works.
I try : ServerAlias 127.0.1.2 in site2.conf
When I try http://127.0.1.2 in windows, i have a error message

Comment: Windows ? This only works in your "guest".

Comment: Hello, 
I try, but seems not works.
I try : ServerAlias 127.0.1.2 in site2.conf
When I try http://127.0.1.2 in windows, i have a error message ("Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.")

Comment: Think my firest message is not clear( i m French sorry)

Comment: VirtualBox is working on windows with i linux server
i can access my two site in linux interface but only site1 in windows

Comment: "localhost" always points to the computer itself. You can not access another computer with "localhost".